# How do i create a dynamic method in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am creating a site using codeigniter with a controller process.php. In its index function it gets a list of countries from my db and lists in in my view with a hyperlink to each country. I would like each link to have a hyperlink of http://localhost/process/$countrycode where $countrycode is dependent on the country being clicked.

How do i create a method to have a link such as: 
http://localhost/process/us for united states
http://localhost/process/ca for canada

the method will perform a task based on the country.

From what i understand with codeigniter urls, it is example.com/class/function/ID but what i would like to achieve is not to include the function in the URL

Comment: your question is not clear can make it little clear

Comment: i need to create a method a method based on the country selected by having the link http://localhost/process/$countrycode

Comment: you mean you want to pass the country code and get the records against the country code am i right.

Comment: yes, but I would like to achieve a url for the method as http://localhost/process/$countrycode where the method performs tasks based on the country

Comment: from what i understand with CI is that you have http://baseurl/controller/method but what i dont want to include the method in the url

Comment: go to your route.php file and add a route like this `$route['add_route_name'] = 'controller/function';` now your url is this http://localhost/process/add_route_name

Comment: why you don't just simply send the country as a `GET` parameter ?

Comment: for parameter you need to use it like this$route['add_route_name/(:any)'] = 'controller/function';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add the new route in your file route.php like this

```
$route['add_route_name'] = 'controller/function';
```

if you want to pass parameters use it like this

```
$route['add_route_name/(:any)'] = 'controller/function';
```

---

for integer

```
$route['add_route_name/(:num)'] = 'controller/function';
```

in codeigniter 3 use `/(.*)` for `(:any)` because the (:any) is not work for All parameters

For example if you want to pass the parameters like this

```
http://localhost/projectname/12/books/etc/
```

in the above url I'm passing 3 parameters which is not getting with `(:any)` but whit `/(.*)` I'm getting the Array of the 3 parameters.

use it like this.

```
$route['add_route_name/(.*)'] = 'controller/function';
```

Comment: i updated my answer if you getting any issue check the answer again Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as far as i understand from your question, you should load view and pass countries to this view as `$this->load->view('view_name',$array('countries'=>$countries_from_db));`
then in view when you fill dropdown for example you will do the following:

```
<?php foreach($countries as $count): <a href ='localhost/process/<?=$country_id?>'><?= $country_name?></a>}
<?php endforeach;?>
```

i wish it helps you :)